# How do I write a bash script to abort a rspec test if it fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, rspec

I am trying to write a script that prevents my applications from turning into WAR files if they do not pass an rspec test. So I am writing a bash script to do this. The code is wrong so please help.

```
CODE:
 bundle exec rspec spec/ --format documentation --fail-fast

#for i in spec/test_spec.rb
#do
if spec/ --fails-fast == true 
 then
        echo 'failed rspec test'
else
        echo "rspec test passed; Warbalize Now!!!!!"
fi
#done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use normal exit codes, since `bundle exec rspec` will preserve the exit code from `rspec`.  E.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! bundle exec rspec spec/ --format documentation --fail-fast; then
  echo "failed rspec test"
else
  echo "rspec test passed; Warbalize Now!!!!!"
fi
```